# I am not getting the desired output for the following PHP code

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am presently in the learning stage.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
    $food=array('Healthy'=>
                        array('Pasta'=>200,'Vegetables'=>300,'Salad'=>100), 

                'Unhealthy'=>
                        array('Pizza','Ice Cream'));
    foreach($food as $element =>$inner_array)   
        echo '<strong>'.$element.'</strong> <br>';
        foreach($inner_array as $inner_element)
        print_r ($inner_element.'<br>');
  ?>
```

The output that I am getting:

```
Healthy 
Unhealthy 
Pizza
Ice Cream
```

I want it to display the digits related to the elements in the inner array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing brackets in both foreach loops, without them only first line after the foreach is executed:

```
$food=array('Healthy'=> array('Pasta'=>200,'Vegetables'=>300,'Salad'=>100), 
            'Unhealthy'=> array('Pizza'=>0,'Ice Cream'=>1));

foreach($food as $element =>$inner_array) {  
    echo '<strong>'.$element.'</strong> <br>';
    foreach($inner_array as $inner_key => $inner_val) {
        print_r ($inner_val.'<br>');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nik0333: This is why you should *always* add the `{}`.  While you *can* omit them, you see why it's not always the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $food=array('Healthy'=> 
                            array('Pasta'=>200,'Vegetables'=>300,'Salad'=>100), 
                'Unhealthy'=> 
                            array('Pizza'=>500,'Ice Cream'=>350));     //Changes made here

    foreach($food as $element =>$inner_array) {

        echo '<strong>'.$element.'</strong> <br>';

    foreach($inner_array as $inner_key => $inner_val)    //Changes made here

        print_r ("$inner_key => $inner_val <br>");       //Changes made here

        }
    ?>
```

This gives the output that I was expecting.